# Parse Push Notification for android not working

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have looked into many questions but i didn't get any push notifications.
I have added all the permissions and have simple receiver. When i debug it shows the device token to be null. In parse the device is detected and the notification is marked to be sent but not received in my device.
I am sharing the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            Parse.initialize(this, "", "");

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Tag 1", e == null ? "Succeed to register the app" : "Failed to register the app", e);
                String deviceToken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
                Log.d("Tag 2", "Device token: " + deviceToken);
            }
        });
```

Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arpan.push_notifivations">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.example.arpan.push_notifivations.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.arpan.push_notifivations.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.arpan.push_notifivations.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.example.arpan.push_notifivations" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The dependencies i added are

```
 compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
```

Comment: Arpan, Please do not create new accounts to upvote your posts. You might think that it is not public, but in fact, everyone will come to know. You might be [suspended](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for this.

Comment: ok sir.my colleague did that.He is new to stack overflow.I don't like fake things either.Will tell him to remove it if he can